# Get the value of above row based on a condition

Tags: sql-server

I get a table data like below

```
pcontact    ccontact    RowOrder    cdatetime               pdatetime
12345678    14121212    1           2021-03-15 10:01:11.497 2021-03-15 09:57:32.803
12345678    14121213    2           2021-03-15 10:04:51.967 2021-03-15 09:57:32.803
12345678    14121214    3           NULL                    2021-03-15 09:57:32.803
```

If the value of cdatetime is **NULL** then I am trying to take value above it, I had tried to use **CASE** statement for it but I am not aware how to proceed further

Please any one point me in the right direction

Comment: What do you mean by "above" - do you mean the preceeding or following row?

Comment: You can use the `LAG` function starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the `lag` function, such as

```
select isnull(cdatetime, lag(cdatetime,1) over (order by RowOrder)) as cdatetime
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, have you tried use TOP?

Rather than:
`SELECT * FROM [Table] BY [ID] = 'some value'`

Try:
`SELECT TOP (1) FROM [Table] WHERE [ID] <= 'some value' AND [cdatetime] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [ID] DESC`

Just a thought.